# Is there a way to inject a DB connection string from a service instead of a configuration for EF-Core DbContextPool

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

My application stores the database connection strings in a secrets vault and not in the config file.
I am attempting to use EF-Core DbContextPool with dependency injection and wondering if I can use the service (IVault,Vault) that has the database connection strings when setting up the DbContextPool instead of the default configuration.

```
  public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            builder.Services.AddSingleton <IVault,Vault>();

            builder.Services.AddDbContextPool<WeatherForecastContext>(

               o => o.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("WeatherForecastContext")));


        }
```

Comment: I am not much into EF, but I see nothing that stops you from changing the `GetConnectionString(string)` into your vault call that would return your connection string.

Comment: You can also follow this way `.AddDbContextPool<MyDbContext>(options =>` then get your connection string. Please [`have a look here`](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/9741#issuecomment-329639080)

Answer (score 2):

Lots of ways you could do it, but an easy one would be to add the connection string to the constructor of your vault class, then during DI you could:

```
Builder.Services.AddSingleton<IVault>(provider => new Vault(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("WeatherForecastContext")));
```